# Craft 3 Custom Field Type with a File Uploader

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, modules

I have a custom field type I am porting from Craft 2 to Craft 3.

This field type used `prepValueFromPost` to grab a reference to a just uploaded file and then saves said file to an appropriate place for temporary storage (the file is sent on to a ticketing system which keeps its own copy so really it's only needed here for a few seconds).  The actual field value is jsut set to the full file path/name as a record.

I'm really struggling to port this across to Craft 3 as this area has seemingly been re-factored a lot...

I think I need to use `serializeValue` in place of `prepValueFromPost`, but I can't grab the actual filename from input in there and the value received is null (I *expected* it to be the filename..but it's not).  I used to use `getContentPostLocation();` for this.

My specific questions are - is serializeValue() the right place to do this?  I want it to occur, once (per field - this is in a matrix), when the element (a Commerce Order) is saved.

And - how do I get the name of the uploaded file (i.e. what has replaced `getContentPostLocation`).

Here is the code that worked in Craft 2.

```
    public function prepValueFromPost($value, $element)
{

    $finalFilePath = null;

    //Weird function that works out the dynamic name of this field
    $filename = $this->getContentPostLocation();
    $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($filename);

    //Save the file where we want it, delete the temporary file
    $outputDir = craft()->path->getTempPath() . "BusinessLogicPlugin_upload_" . time();
    IOHelper::ensureFolderExists($outputDir);
    //Was needed on dev, can't really hurt...leave it here.
    chmod($outputDir, 0775);

    $finalFilePath = $outputDir ."/" . $file->name;

    if(!($file->saveAs($finalFilePath, false))){
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("Unable to save actual file [$finalFilePath], file will not be attached");
        $finalFilePath = "";
    }

    //Save the pathname of the file, if we were able to save it, otherwise empty string.
    return $finalFilePath;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind Craft 3 default form does not have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so you won't be able to upload files with this form. You can include custom JavaScript to add this tag to the `Craft.cp.$primaryForm` otherwise it's not possible to include an upload like that

Comment: Yep already doing that, thanks via some js in the field template. But need to work out the rest still!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as a little example how to store files in a custom field

```PHP
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function normalizeValue($value, ElementInterface $element = null)
{

    $namespace = $element? $element->getFieldParamNamespace() . '.' : '';
    $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($namespace . $this->handle);
    if($file !== null){
        // replace this
        $somePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->name;
        $file->saveAs($somePath);
    }
    return $file;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getInputHtml($value, ElementInterface $element = null): string
{
    Craft::$app->getView()->registerJs('Craft.cp.$primaryForm.attr(\'enctype\', \'multipart/form-data\');');
    return '<input type="file" name="' . $this->handle . '">';
}
```

#### Edit:

If you want to store the file path in your Database you would check if `$value` is an instance of `File` and if so return the path. Otherwise just declare your field has `contentColumn = false`

Comment: Robin - thank you so very much!  This works a treat.  I had thought to use `serializeValue` to save the file when the field value is being saved to the DB - this feels the more logical spot (still!)  But this definitely works & is very much appreciated.